# Father of a nation and his children

Tags: knowledge

The father of a nation who was a statesman had 8 children who are listed as follows:

> 1. An annual music prize
> 2. A tennis player
> 3. Best Picture winner at Academy Award
> 4. A singer-songwriter
> 5. An episode of Battlestar Galactica
> 6. A home video game console
> 7. A high-ranking Byzantine General
> 8. Two groups of islands in South Australia

***Identify the names of the father and his children.***

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An annual music prize

> The **Mercury** Prize

A tennis player

> **Venus** Williams

Best Picture winner at Academy Award

> The Greatest Show on **Earth**

A singer-songwriter

> Bruno **Mars**

An episode of Battlestar Galactica

> The Eye of **Jupiter**

A home video game console

> Sega **Saturn**

A high-ranking Byzantine General

> [Nicephorus **Uranus**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikephoros_Ouranos)

Two groups of islands in South Australia

> [**Neptune** Islands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neptune_Islands)

The father is

> [**Sun** Yat-sen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Yat-sen) -  first provisional president of the Republic of China and called the Father of the Nation.

Comment: Thank you @chandanr777 for commenting there's more weight to the Father of the Nation.